# Links that work both in Markdown and after build with Jekyll

Tags: hyperlink, markdown, jekyll

I am currently creating a multi-page markdown documentation that I want to use both as simple markdown reference and as source code for a Jekyll site. I am having trouble with formulating links in a way that works for both worlds.

Obviously, I tried to set simple links in a markdown document like this:

```
[some link](path/to/file.md)
```

This works nicely with any markdown viewer, allowing users to browse the markdown documentation.

However, this does not work with Jekyll as intended. After compilation, Jekyll translates these links to

```
<a href="path/to/file.md">some link</a>
```

which is not what I want, of course. I want it to link to the translated `path/to/file.html` (or maybe `path/to/file/index.html` or whatever).

I found that Jekyll understands all sorts of ways to formulate links. For example, this triggers translation:

```
[some link](path/to/file)
```

However, if I write my links with Jekyll-specific syntax, I can not use the code with markdown viewers anymore. Is there any way to formulate links that work with both worlds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this gem to achieve expected behaviour:
https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links

Be aware that you might need to enable converting collection links with:

```
relative_links:
  enabled:     true
  collections: true
```